# Combinatorial sums, a possible formula for inserting a dummy variable in the front?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I've recently been working with combinatorial sums (I love the mix of algebra and combinatorics!). When working with some basic problems, I have found a pattern that may or may not be true.

**Example 1:** Consider $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}$. It is well known that this is equivalent to $2^n$. Now what happens when we insert a $k$ in the front? It becomes $\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}$. This is actually not too difficult to evaluate if we do some manipulation. It turns out to be $n\cdot 2^{n-1}$.

**Example 2:** Consider $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}$. Let's try to evaluate it. Observing the $a^{n-k}$, we think of the binomial theorem. In fact, this is the expansion for $(1+a)^n$. Now what happens if we insert the $k$ in there again? I checked this with Mathematica and it seems  as if it evaluates to $n(1+a)^{n-1}$.

There are multiple other examples. My  hypothesis is as follows:

*Given a function $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}f(k)=x^n$, where $x$ is some constant, we have that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}kf(k)=nx^{n-1}$.*

Is this even true? If it is, how do we prove this?

**Note: Since $\int nx^{n-1}=x^n+C$, and integrals have a relationship with summations, I think calculus may be needed to prove/disprove the hypothesis.**

Comment: Not quite. Your example is "Given $\sum f(n,k) = x^n$", whereas your hypothesis is "Given $ \sum f(k) = x^n$. In fact, your hypothesis (as stated) isn't true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only function that satisfies $ \sum_{k=0}^n f(k) = x^n$ is $ f(n) = x^n - (x-1)^n$.

So, is $ \sum kf(k) = \sum k ( x^k - (x-1)^k)  = nx^{n-1}$?

Unfortunately, no.